# Firefox not using GTK theme on KDE Plasma

Tags: 16.04, firefox, kde, gtk, plasma

Firefox is not using my GTK theme, Numix Solarized Dark. I am running KDE Plasma. How could I set it to use my theme?

Comment: Did you look at `System Settings`, `Application Style`, `GNOME Application Style`, `Select a GTK3 Theme`?

Comment: Yes, I did. NumixSolarizedDark is selected.

Answer (score 0):

I found out why this was not working. I could not get Firefox themed properly even on a GTK-based desktop environment. Firefox apparently dropped support for GTK themes a while ago, so it won't be themed accordingly.